# Google Custom Search API returns different total number of results

Tags: python-3.x, google-custom-search

Google Custom Search API returns a different total number of results compared when I normally use my web browser to search google.

On the Custom Search Control Panel, Search the entire web is turned ON. I followed [this](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631040?hl=en) set-up, it says '*Note that results may not match the results you'd get by searching on Google Web Search*',

why is that?

Here is my code:

```
def main():

  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
            developerKey="my-key")

  res = service.cse().list(
      q='allintitle: hotels tokyo',
      cx='my-key',
      num=10,
    ).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**results :**

```
searchInformation': {'formattedSearchTime': '0.41',
                       'formattedTotalResults': '5,260',
                       'searchTime': 0.408312,
                       'totalResults': '5260'}
```

**Normal browser results :**

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: For me the same search returns Page 1 of about 87,900 results (0.67 seconds) - I think what it factors also is images and maps, note when I get to the last page I hit the "We've omitted some results, click here to view them" which means the public UI essentially has a different algo than CSE (though the schema pull is the same, in reality and by geographic region) results do varie.

Comment: API do not use synonyms, so number of results is much smaller for it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is of use still, I had this problem and for me it turned out that I was setting the "dateRestrict" variable to 14 days in the Python call, meaning that the results were, of course different.